# Get date created of video from UIPickerViewController - Swift

Tags: swift

If you present a UIImagePickerController with a source type of .camera or .photoLibrary (Swift), how can you get the date taken in UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.

Comment: Hint: `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker) (YPImagePicker) pod for get videos detail.

Comment: Why would you need somebody else's library when in fact all you have to do is read the meta data of the selected file?